# How to use print Statement to display data present in columns of a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table with 4 columns, I want to print the data present in two columns as text using a `Print` statement. How can I do that ?

Comment: Why do you want to print?

Comment: Yes,I am writing a SQL code

Comment: Did you try using the plus (+) sign??   Is there some reason it didn't work?   Please post your attempt and what errors you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of cursor or while loop..
simply write a select query by cobining your columns and change the option to result to text in ssms as in the below screen shot and then execute.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure of your requirement, but below code is the way using cursor. If your table has large records, use WHILE loop.

```
Declare @a varchar(10)
Declare @b varchar(10)

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR  
select col1, col2 from Table
    OPEN MyCursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @a, @b   
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       Print @a + ' ' + @b
       FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @a, @b  
END   
CLOSE MyCursor   
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pinwar13, i am able to print the data present in the column but i am missing the column names :(

Comment: there would be no difference between a cursor and a while loop

Comment: @ManojKumar you should just click the "Results to text" option in SSMS